# What to do next when you get core backtrace pointing to libc?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, coredump, libc

So, I messed up and want to know why... and turns out, I have a coredump to tell me why. But the coredump tells me,

```
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f4e36c08c0c in __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=40, signo=6, no_tid=<optimized out>) at pthread_kill.c:66
#1  0x00007f4e36bb8986 in killpg (pgrp=40, sig=40) at ../sysdeps/posix/killpg.c:28
#2  0x00007f4e36d73e90 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f4e36ba27f4 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#4  0x00007f4e36bfcd5e in __libc_message (action=<optimized out>, fmt=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:156
#5  0x00007f4e36c1295c in int_mallinfo (av=0x0, m=0x8) at malloc.c:5167
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

My code messed up malloc structs somehow, triggering a SIGABRT from libc? Frightening, but the info is insufficient to root cause anything.

So, my question is - what is the most useful next course of action here? Is there any way to wring more info from this coredump?

Comment: Run under valgrind or recompile with AddressSanitizer and try to reproduce. One other popular way to corrupt the heap is locking problems with multithreading, that one can only be resolved with careful detective work and lots of luck. I don't think you will be able to mine one core file for much useful information.

Comment: The signal happens when the stack or heap corruption is detected, not when it occurs. That may have happened much earlier in far other worlds and other seas.

Answer (score 2):

> My code messed up malloc structs somehow, triggering a SIGABRT from libc?

Most probably.

> What to do next when you get core backtrace pointing to libc?
>
> what is the most useful next course of action here?

Inspect *your* code and find a bug in your code.

Use compiler instrumentation to detect invalid code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer . The `-fsanitize=undefined,address,pointer-compare,pointer-subtract -Wall -Wextra -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-clash-protection -fstack-protector-all -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -fcf-protection -Wwrite-strings -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fexceptions -fpie -Wl,-pie` is something I use. Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind . Statically check your program with https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint .

> Is there any way to wring more info from this coredump?

There are many introductions to gdb online, you can show registers and inspect other threads.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but ultimately we reproduced on production and simply ran the process under gdb, that go us to the solution (passing a nullptr to a library)